# How to change the look and feel of exposed filters in a block

Tags: 7, views

I have view which has exposed filters. I have configured those filters to block.
But now I want to change the look and feel of the exposed filters .

How to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more control over your exposed form template, you an write a template file for it. This [article](http://lyphuong.drupalgardens.com/content/how-display-views-exposed-filter-block-and-theme-it) will help you to define template file.

Otherwise you can change the appearance with css, And you can use form alter in case of alter any elements.